# Difference Between Two Joda DateTime In Months and Left Over Days

Tags: java, android, jodatime, period, date-difference

I have a requirement to get the amount of months between two `DateTime` objects and then get the number of days left over.

Here is how I get the months between:

`Months monthsBetween = Months.monthsBetween(dateOfBirth,endDate);`

I am unsure how to then find out how many days are left over into the next month. I have tried the following:

```
int offset = Days.daysBetween(dateOfBirth,endDate)
              .minus(monthsBetween.get(DurationFieldType.days())).getDays();
```

But this does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `org.joda.time.Period`:

```
// fields used by the period - use only months and days
PeriodType fields = PeriodType.forFields(new DurationFieldType[] {
        DurationFieldType.months(), DurationFieldType.days()
    });
Period period = new Period(dateOfBirth, endDate)
    // normalize to months and days
    .normalizedStandard(fields);
```

The normalization is needed because the period usually creates things like "1 month, 2 weeks and 3 days", and the normalization converts it to "1 month and 17 days". Using the specific `DurationFieldType`'s above also makes it convert years to months automatically.

Then you can get the number of months and days:

```
int months = period.getMonths();
int days = period.getDays();
```

Another detail is that when using `DateTime` objects, the `Period` will also consider the time (hour, minute, secs) to know if a day has passed.

If you want to ignore the time and consider only the date (day, month and year), don't forget to convert them to `LocalDate`:

```
// convert DateTime to LocalDate, so time is ignored
Period period = new Period(dateOfBirth.toLocalDate(), endDate.toLocalDate())
    // normalize to months and days
    .normalizedStandard(fields);
```